# Is a question about the "why" behind a technical part of an emulator allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'd like to ask about why PS2 emulators can't/won't play PS1 games when the physical PS2 was actually able to play them, but I have an inkling that it's off topic here. Is that the case?

Comment: I wonder if it would be a good fit for Retrocomputing Stack Exchange.Probably not...

Comment: There was this Stackexchange question where someone asked how a fading out effect was done on a somewhat older Harvest Moon game, I can't remember on which Stack Exchange website it was. Edit: It was indeed on Retrocomputing. Might be worth asking on Meta if it's allowed to ask about emulator over there too.

Comment: Following Clockwork's comment, I found [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13531/15988) on Retrocomputing. It's not the same question, but it discusses why/how the PS2 implemented backwards compatibility, which might answer your question about why PS2 emulators can't play PS1 games